Notepad with tree structure?
I am looking for a text editor that lets me create and see the tree structure in a separate side pane like some outliner software such as Treepad.
But I don't need tons of features with fancy interface which makes the program more or less sluggish. I don't need font and text formatting as well as importing pictures or tables. I don't need for rich text in any way. Just plain text and tree. That's it.
Is there basically a text editor that is lightweight and fast, while supporting tree structure to nagivate the file more easily?

Because you want light and fast, and you're using Windows, I can recommend MemPad by Horst Schaeffer.  I've personally used MemPad, and it works quite well.  On the left side, you get a tree structure to organize your notes, and on the right you get an editing pane to enter your text.  It's fast and efficient.  It's a portable application. The current version is only 229KB!
The big feature I find it missing is a spell-checker.
MemPad is closed-source freeware.
MemPad screenshot:

image source: https://www.horstmuc.de/wmem.htm

Thank you this is so good hierarchical editor actually. Very simple but responsive. But I think it would be much better if users can choose whether or not  they want to save the current file before exiting. Repetitive undoing or having bak file with original is not so desirable experience. Even force close doesn't prevent it from saving.

If you desire something cross-platform, or want an integrated spell-checker, I can recommend CherryTree by Giuseppe Penone (AKA giuspen) and Evgenii Gurianov (AKA txe).
CherryTree is available for Windows, Linux, and macOS.  There's even a third-party Android app called SourCherry that allows you to read CherryTree files on Android and perform some editing.
CherryTree include import functionality to import data from a variety of formats.
CherryTree is feature-rich, but still fast.  The authors completely rewrote CherryTree in recent years, greatly improving it.
CherryTree includes powerful search functionality.  I do hope they improve the UI/UX for search in the future, as I find it cumbersome (and is the only part of CherryTree that can be a bit slow).
CherryTree is open source freeware.  Donations are accepted here.
CherryTree screenshot:

image source: https://www.giuspen.net/cherrytree/

Many thanks. The fact it is open source is good plus. and I think it can be used as word processors too.

Check out Obsidian, it's available for Windows, Linux and Mac.
And also for mobile devices on Android and iOS.
It allows you to create a tree structure of folders and files.
All files are stored locally in Markdown format.
To use it on Linux you need to install FUSE, details at the link.

Some people on the interwebs seem to recommend Obsidian a lot in recent months, but I don't quite get it.  It has some nice functionality, but was slow and lethargic in my experience.  Also, when I tried it, I couldn't find any way to search across all notes, which is basic & essential functionality.  Have they added that functionality, or was I somehow not able to find it?

@AmazonDiesInDarkness It has a search function for all notes - the magnifying glass is in the upper left corner. Yes, there has been a lot of hype around it lately. I don't use it all the time, but rather installed it to get acquainted with in my free time.

Thanks! Is that something new (and are you sure)? When I used it last (which was a little while back), that magnifying glass in the upper-left corner wouldn't search all notes.  I read the documentation to be sure, then uninstalled it. I then tried it again a few months later, and it still didn't search all notes. I was really surprised, because it's so essential.  IIRC, each note was stored in a separate file, and Obsidian's search could only search within one file.  It's been several months since I looked at it though.

@AmazonDiesInDarkness Better to show it visually. Search for the word cat, which appears in several files (android, gazelle and others). Proofs here https://imgur.com/a/qK8MbK3

Thanks so much! That looks great!!! I like that it shows the number of occurrences per file too.  Can you quickly click on any search result to go to that position in the appropriate file?

@AmazonDiesInDarkness yes.

I use Visual Studio Code for this. I split the panel in two and have different sections under a tree structure. I use this with my to-do lists.

